# change list into a data frame but keep the number of list order

Tags: r

I have a `list` with `length` of 14. Within each row, some of them are `NULL` value, and some of them have multiple numbers. This is the list:

```
> start_positions
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] 1517

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
[1] 1410

[[10]]
[1] 5995

[[11]]
NULL

[[12]]
[1] 13880 24631

[[13]]
NULL

[[14]]
[1] 18622
```

I want to unlist it and delete those `NULL` values,but keep the number of the order of `list`, like this:

```
list    start_positions
4       1517
9       1410
10      5995
12      13880
12      24631
14      18622
```

I tried `rbind()` and `do.call()` with `unlist()`, but it just gave me only one column and rank it from 1. (I think I should name each one of the row? but I don't know how.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a warning because of the `NULL` values, but you can use `stack`:

```
myList <- list(NULL, NULL, 1, 2, NULL, c(3, 4)) ## Sample data
stack(setNames(myList, seq_along(myList)))
#   values ind
# 1      1   3
# 2      2   4
# 3      3   6
# 4      4   6
# Warning message:
# In stack.default(setNames(myList, seq_along(myList))) :
#   non-vector elements will be ignored
```

---

If you want to avoid the warning, you can subset the list *after* naming it:

```
names(myList) <- seq_along(myList)
stack(myList[!sapply(myList, is.null)])
```

---

Note that in any case `stack` needs `names`. In the first example, I added them "on the fly" using `setNames`, and in the second example, I added them directly.